# How can I integrate PayPal subscribe button in my android app?

Tags: android, paypal

Can I somehow integrate PayPal subscribe button in my android app? Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if paypal had a mobile version, but I think it's possible when you create a paypal button on your app to open a web view that linkage to paypal payment. Hope it'll help you... :)